# CSS Set dynamic value depend on class

Tags: css

I want to add style depends on a class that has uncertain suffix generated programmaticaly. consider we have css class like this
`child-0`,`child-1`, and so on, but we don't know if it would be 0,1, or 69 in the class because it generated as i said before. is it possible to define rule like this?

```
.child-var{
   padding-left:2+var px
}
```

or there is any way to do this in css?

Comment: this is a trivial use case for SASS/LESS

Comment: If you were to use SCSS rather than CSS you could do this in a loop - examples here http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while